# Having trouble setting size with nyroModal v2

Tags: nyromodal

I'm just now starting to work with nyroModal. After going nuts trying to figure out why the nyroModalSettings vanished (appears that was pre-v2... or so I gather), I got a little closer to making options work.

This, for instance, works fine for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.nyroModal').nm({showCloseButton: false});
        });
</script>
```

My popups will come up with no close button, as expected.

Following that syntax, I thought this should work to bring up a smaller box than the default:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.nyroModal').nm({sizes: {w: 100, h: 100}});
        });
</script>
```

No go. No syntax errors, etc... just no impact on the box size whatsoever.

I tried using the initW and initH options as well.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!
 - Aaron

Answer (score 4):

I worked around this trouble to open an iframe. I had to use this options to set up dimensions and fix them before iframe was shown.
Anyway, this works fine for me:

```
var width = 800;
var height = 600;
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal({
  sizes: {
    initW: width, initH: height,
    minW: width, minH: height,
    w: width, h: height
  },
  callbacks: {
    beforeShowCont: function() { 
        width = $('.nyroModalCont').width();
        height = $('.nyroModalCont').height();
        $('.nyroModalCont iframe').css('width', width);
        $('.nyroModalCont iframe').css('height', height);
    }
  }
});
```

I hope this can help you.